# How to change the position of a div to another div when rezise

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

**Scenario :**

- I have two `div`. 
  One div is title and another is form.
- But when I resize it in some screen mobile it not correct.

**Todo :**

- I want when I resize in some screen margin left div title and div form.
  It
  mean when resize margin left of title according to the margin left div form.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you please share the markup(html)

Answer (score -2):

I hope that I am getting this correct. My understanding is that you are hoping to place the title above the form when viewing on a mobile screen. This is easily done using media queries. See below. [W3Schools | Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .div1 {
        display: block;
     }

     .div 2 {
        display: block;    
     }
}

.div1 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 40%;
}

.div 2 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 40%;
}
```

Media queries are powerful because you can use them to dynamically filter styling methods like setting the divs above to display as block. (Filling the entire width of it's container) instead of being placed on the same line as the other block and taking only 40% of it's container. If needed, please **submit a markup** for review.